({"err":{"InstructionError":[1,"ExternalAccountLamportSpend"]}})
Got this error while buying NFT :-
    pub fn buy_nft(ctx: Context<BuyNft>) -> Result<()> {
            msg!("Buying nft");
    
            let pda_account = &ctx.accounts.pda_account;
            let seller = &ctx.accounts.seller;
            let buyer = &ctx.accounts.buyer;
    
            let bump = &[ctx.bumps.pda_signer];
            let binding = ctx.accounts.mint.key();
            let signer_seeds = &[&[b"sale", binding.as_ref(), bump][..]];
    
            token::transfer(
                CpiContext::new_with_signer(
                    ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                    Transfer {
                        from: ctx.accounts.pda_token_account.to_account_info(),
                        to: ctx.accounts.buyer_token_account.to_account_info(),
                        authority: ctx.accounts.pda_signer.to_account_info(),
                    },
                    signer_seeds,
                ),
                1,
            )?;
    
            **seller.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += pda_account.price;
            **buyer.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= pda_account.price;
    
            Ok(())
        }
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct BuyNft<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    /// CHECK: Validate address by deriving pda
    #[account(mut)]
    pub seller: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub pda_account: Account<'info, Sale>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub pda_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    /// CHECK: Validate address by deriving pda
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"sale", mint.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub pda_signer: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

This is a test case :-
it('Buy NFT', async () => {
      const buyerTokenAccountAddress = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
        mintKeyPair.publicKey,
        buyerKeypair.publicKey
    );

    const [pdaAccount, bump] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
        [Buffer.from('sale'), mintKeyPair.publicKey.toBuffer()],
        program.programId
    );

    const pdaTokenAccountAddress = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
        mintKeyPair.publicKey,
        pdaAccount,
        true
    );

    const createBuyerTokenAccountIx = createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        payer.publicKey,
        buyerTokenAccountAddress,
        buyerKeypair.publicKey,
        mintKeyPair.publicKey
    );

    try {
        const buyTransactionSignature = await program.methods
            .buyNft()
            .accounts({
                buyer: buyerKeypair.publicKey,
                buyerTokenAccount: buyerTokenAccountAddress,
                seller: payer.publicKey,
                pdaAccount,
                pdaTokenAccount: pdaTokenAccountAddress,
                mint: mintKeyPair.publicKey,
                pdaSigner: pdaAccount,
                tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
            })
            .preInstructions([createBuyerTokenAccountIx])
            .signers([buyerKeypair])
            .rpc({ skipPreflight: true });

        console.log('NFT purchased');
        console.log('Transaction signature', buyTransactionSignature);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error buying NFT:', error);
    }
    });


An account that is not owned by a program must use transfer. I'm assuming buyer and seller here are owned by the System Program and that you cannot modify their balance within your program.
use anchor_lang::{
    system_program::Transfer,
};
  let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.buyer.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.seller.to_account_info(),
        };
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info();

        let cpi_context: CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, '_, Transfer<'_>> =
            CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);

        system_program::transfer(cpi_context, pda_account.price)?; 


It worked by doing this :-
pub fn buy_nft(ctx: Context<BuyNft>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Buying nft");

        let pda_account = &ctx.accounts.pda_account;
        let seller = &ctx.accounts.seller;
        let buyer = &ctx.accounts.buyer;

        let bump = &[ctx.bumps.pda_signer];
        let binding = ctx.accounts.mint.key();
        let signer_seeds = &[&[b"sale", binding.as_ref(), bump][..]];

        token::transfer(
            CpiContext::new_with_signer(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.pda_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.buyer_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.pda_signer.to_account_info(),
                },
                signer_seeds,
            ),
            1,
        )?;

        system_program::transfer(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                system_program::Transfer {
                    from: buyer.to_account_info(),
                    to: seller.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            pda_account.price,
        )?;

        Ok(())
    }

